# In Polymer 1.0 I cannot add other elements to a paper-radio-group without them stealing the selection when clicked

Tags: polymer

I have a page that looks like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-radio-group/paper-radio-group.html'>
    <style>
        paper-radio-button {
            display: block;
        }

        .indent {
            padding-left:40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <paper-radio-group selected='A'>
        <paper-radio-button name='A'>A</paper-radio-button>
        <div class='indent'>Click on me</div>
        <paper-radio-button name='B'>B</paper-radio-button>
        <div class='indent'>Or me</div>
    </paper-radio-group>
</body>
```

My problem is that when the page is rendered, it will show that A is selected, but if I e.g. click This is the radiobutton for A div, then the selection from the radiobutton is removed. How can I add my html tags and only have the actual radio buttons decide on the selection in the paper-radio-group?

Cheers

Franz

Comment: Anyone? ... this worked in 0.5 and was hoping for a solution in 1.0

Comment: I cannot replicate this behavior.  The code you provided seems to be OK.  Do you have a live example?  You should change `<script src='bower_components/polymer/polymer.html'></script>` to `<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" />`.

Comment: Yes, you are right ... I have updated the code. But if you show above, "A" will be selected, but the moment you click on the "Click on me" text, the selection in "A" disappears ...... it doesn't do that in your end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when I upgraded to the latest version of Polymer the problem had been solved